# (Javascript and Html) function doing another function which its not told to do

Tags: javascript, html, image, function, input

***was building a form and had 2 file inputs which I intended to (once a file was uploaded) set the background of the input container to the image that was uploaded,***

i used labels to hide the default button and change it to my own

this was one of the inputs and its container

```
<div class="input_container" id="img_A">
  <input onchange="changeA(event)" class="file_input" name="fileA" type="file">
  <label for="file_input">
    <img src="../images/add_icon.png" id="img_add">
  </label>
</div>
```

and the second one

```
<div class="input_container" id="img_B">
  <input onchange="changeB(event)" class="file_input" name="fileB" type="file">
  <label for="file_input">
    <img src="../images/add_icon.png" id="img_add">
  </label>
</div>
```

and the js functions

```
function changeA(event){
  var getImagePathA = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
  $('#img_A').css('background-image', 'url(' + getImagePathA + ')');
}
function changeB(event){
  var getImagePathB = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
  $('#img_B').css('background-image', 'url(' + getImagePathB + ')');
}
```

but the result is that when I use the second input it sets the background to the image uploaded but of the first box and not the one I click

when i tested this with alerts the second input seems to be running the changeA(event) and not changeB(event)

thank you in advance for any help at all!

Comment: Looks like a typo in the changeB function, as the query selector is looking for `#timg_B` instead of `#img_B`

Comment: corrected it and still doesnt work, however thank you as it would of caused more confusion for me!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the same `../images/add_icon.png` image file. So when you click the second input, it's still pointing towards `../images/add_icon.png`.

you should try:

```
<div class="input_container" id="img_A">
  <input onchange="changeA(event)" class="file_input" name="fileA" type="file">
  <label for="file_input">
    <img src="../images/image_file_A.png" id="img_add">
  </label>
</div>

<div class="input_container" id="img_B">
  <input onchange="changeB(event)" class="file_input" name="fileB" type="file">
  <label for="file_input">
    <img src="../images/image_file_B.png" id="img_add">
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: i dont want to change the img background of <img> as thats just the icon button to click to add a file its just a blue background with a plus on, i want to change the background of the input_container to the upload